# awk NR%2{}1 meaning

Tags: awk

I am trying to understand this code:

```bsh
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' yourFile
```

Now I try to customize it.

Given this error.txt content:

```
KEY 4048:1736 string
3
KEY 0:1772 string
1
KEY 4192:1349 string
1
KEY 7329:2407 string
2
KEY 0:1774 string
1
```

Then:

```bsh
awk 'NR%2{printf NR "%s ", $0; next}1' error.txt
```

... will return:

```
1KEY 4048:1736 string 3
3KEY 0:1772 string 1
5KEY 4192:1349 string 1
7KEY 7329:2407 string 2
9KEY 0:1774 string 1
```

I guess `NR%2` refer to even line numbers, but I am not sure what the `1` refers to.
Without `1`,  `awk 'NR%2{printf NR "%s ", $0; next}' error.txt`
will return one line.

```
1KEY 4048:1736 string 3KEY 0:1772 string 5KEY 4192:1349 string 7KEY 7329:2407 string 9KEY 0:1774 string
```

Overall, I am still not getting it.

I've looked at these pages so far:

- https://www.tecmint.com/use-next-command-with-awk-in-linux/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482224/15603477
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605559/15603477

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for a quick awk primer.

Comment: I guess it should be `printf "%d%s ", NR, $0` instead of `printf NR "%s ", $0`. But it still works somehow? Interesting...

Comment: Ok, so NR is concatenated with the format string to form a longer format string with the line number embedded at the beginning.

Comment: It's a convoluted way to write `paste -d ' ' - - < error.txt` or `paste -sd ' \n' error.txt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

that `%` is [Modulus/Remainder arithmetic operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html), which finds the modulus division of two or more numbers. the `NR` in awk represents the current record number which its division by 2 where it's written as a *condition statement*, that results with 0 for even records numbers and so 0 is a false result therfore the followed *action* is not performed and;

the `1` at the end, an idiom as known as always true condition will be executed that prints the even line numbers at the end of previous lines (it runs whenever the `NR%2` result 0) where those are printed with `printf` without line break. see [What is the meaning of '1' at the end of an awk script](/q/63891/72456)

Answer (score -1):

found a ***much*** better solution that works across the board :

```
gawk/mawk/nawk '(ORS=ORS?"":"\n")~_'
```

Because by default awk's `ORS` is always pre-populated with a single `\n`, this method always ensures joining even numbered lines to the one just above it, without having to waste time doing `NR % 2` when all one needs is to test whether ORS is an empty string or not.

===========old post below===============================

you can bring the conditional inside without all the next stuff :

```
gawk/mawk/nawk '{ printf("%s%c",$0,23^(NR%2)+9) }'
```

On odd-number lines, the `NR%2` evaluates to 1 (true),

- `so 23^1+9 = 32 = ascii space.`

For even-number lines, it gets a 0/false,

- `so 23^0+9 = 1+9 = 10 = ascii new line \n`