# AWK printf syntax

Tags: awk

I though that the syntax for printf statements is `printf format, item1, item2, ...` as described e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html)

However, in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685721/awk-nr21-meaning) printf is used like this: `printf NR "%s ", $0` and it works! Why? Is it expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two features at work here: `printf`, and [AWK string concatenation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html). `NR "%s "` produces the concatenation of the value of `NR` and the string `%s` ; that is then given to `printf` as its first argument.

A clearer way of writing this would be

```
printf "%d%s ", NR, $0
```

Comment: Also, because `NR` is being used in a string operation (concatenation) that number is being converted to a string (as if by `sprintf("%d", NR)`, it would have been `sprintf(CONVFMT, NR)` had it been a float).

Comment: Could also be written: `printf "%s", NR $0 " "` or `ORS=""; print NR $0 " "`

Answer (score 0):

suggest to change `%d` to `%.f`, since mawk-1.3.4 that's common in many linux distributions has a limitaton for very large files with `%d/%u` that can only be circumvented via `%.f` :

```
% date | mawk  '{ NR=9E9-7; printf("%d\f%s\n",NR,$0) }'
2147483647
          Tue Jan 18 01:49:52 EST 2022

% date | mawk  '{ NR=9E9-7; printf("%.f\f%s\n",NR,$0) }'
8999999993
          Tue Jan 18 01:49:58 EST 2022
```